# Does $|T(f) - T(g)| \leq |T(f-g)|$ hold for a sublinear operator $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be function spaces with functions taking values in $\mathbf{C}$. An operator $T:X\to Y$ is called sublinear if for all $f,g \in X$ and all $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$, we have
$$
|T(\lambda f)| = |\lambda| |T(f)|
$$ 
and
$$
|T(f+g)| \leq |T(f)| + |T(g)|.
$$
My question is if any such operator also satisfies
$$|T(f) - T(g)| \leq |T(f-g)|$$
for any functions $f,g \in X$. If not, what is an example in which this fails? I'm thinking it is not true, but I have not been successful in constructing such an example. The reason we're interested in such an inequality is that if it is true in general, then we can prove a certain operator defined on characteristic functions can be extended to all functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider
$$
T(f)=\Vert f\Vert e^{i \Vert f\Vert}
$$
and constant function $f=\pi$ and $g=2\pi$.

Comment: I'm glad this is bounded from $L^p(X)$ to $L^q(Y)$ if $X,Y$  are finite measure spaces. What if they aren't finite?

Comment: then multiply $f$ and $g$ by chraracterictic function of the set of suitable measure.

Comment: Oh! Duh... Thanks for the example!

Comment: you are wellcome!